# no viable alternative at input 'int ' - ANTLR 4 with Python Parser

Tags: python, antlr

I got the problem when dealing with ANTLR4 and Parse by Python Library.

The grammar:

```
grammar SimpleCode;           
program  : 'class' ' ' 'Program' ' ' '{'  field_decl* method_decl*  '}' ;
field_decl : DATA_TYPE variable (',' variable)* ';' ;
method_decl: (DATA_TYPE | 'void')  identifier '(' method_params? ')' block ;
variable : identifier | identifier '[' int_literal ']' ;
method_params : DATA_TYPE identifier (',' DATA_TYPE identifier)* ;
block : '{' var_decl* statement* '}' ;
var_decl : DATA_TYPE identifier (',' identifier)* ';';
statement : location assign_op expr ';' | method_call ';' | 'if' '(' (expr) ')' block ('else' block)? | 'for' identifier '=' (expr) ',' (expr) block | 'return' (expr)? ';' | 'break' ';' | 'continue' ';' | block ;
assign_op : '=' | '+=' | '-=' ;
method_call : method_name '(' method_call_params? ')' | 'callout' (string_literal (',' callout_arg (',' callout_arg)*)?) ;
method_call_params : DATA_TYPE identifier (',' DATA_TYPE identifier)* ;
method_name : identifier ;
location : identifier | identifier '[' expr ']' ;
expr : location | method_call | literal | expr bin_op expr | '-' expr | '!' expr | '(' expr ')' ;
callout_arg : expr | string_literal ;
bin_op : arith_op | rel_op | eq_op | cond_op ;
arith_op : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' + '%' ;
rel_op : '<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=' ;
eq_op : '==' | '!=' ;
cond_op : '&&' | '||' ;
literal : int_literal | char_literal | bool_literal ;
identifier : ALPHA alpha_num* ;
alpha_num : ALPHA | DIGIT ;
int_literal : decimal_literal | hex_literal ;
decimal_literal : DIGIT DIGIT* ;
hex_literal : '0x' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT* ;
bool_literal : 'true' | 'false' ;
CHAR: . ;
char_literal : '\'' CHAR '\''  ;
string_literal : '"' CHAR* '"' ;


DATA_TYPE : INT | BOOL ;

INT : 'int' ;
BOOL : 'boolean' ;
ALPHA : [a-zA-Z] ;
DIGIT : [0-9] ;
HEX_DIGIT : [0-9a-fA-F] ;

White : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
Newline : ( '\r' '\n'? | '\n' ) -> skip ;
LineComment : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip ;
```

My python code to parse:

```
from antlr4 import *
from SimpleCodeLexer import SimpleCodeLexer
from SimpleCodeListener import SimpleCodeListener
from SimpleCodeParser import SimpleCodeParser
import sys

class SimpleCodePrintListener(SimpleCodeListener):
    def enterProgram(self, ctx):
        print(ctx.getText())
        print(ctx.toStringTree())
        # for child in ctx.getChildren():
        #     print(child.getText(), child.getSymbol())

def main():
    input_stream = FileStream('in.in')
    lexer = SimpleCodeLexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = SimpleCodeParser(stream)
    tree = parser.program()
    printer = SimpleCodePrintListener()
    walker = ParseTreeWalker()
    walker.walk(printer, tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting parse....')
    main()
```

And the **in.in** file:

```
class Program {
    int main() {
        int v;
        v = 1;
        v = 'c';
        v = true;
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

I got this error after run the python code:

**line 2:7 no viable alternative at input 'int '**

The result of the first print is:

**class Program {int main() {int v;v = 1;v = 'c';v = true;return 0; }}**

```
([] class   Program   { int   m a i n ( )   { int   v ; v   =   1 ; v   =   ' c ' ; v   =   true ; return   0 ;   } })
```

I'm newbie to ANTLR4, so are there any special case to handle with lexers and tokens, because after hours of searching on internet, the main problem is about DATA_TYPE is used at many different places in grammar.

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate on what problem you are facing or want to solve?

Comment: @Tony I got warning "no viable alternative at input 'int '", then it's difficult to parse tree of whole code in file "in.in"

Answer (score 1):

When debugging issues like this, it often helps to print the token stream that's generated for the given input. You can do that by running `grun` with the option `-tokens` or by iterating over `stream` in your `main` function.

If you do that, you'll see that `main` is tokenized as a sequence of four `CHAR` tokens, whereas your `identifier` rule expects `ALPHA` tokens, not `CHAR`. So that's the immediate problem, but it's not the only problem in your code:

- The first thing I noticed when I tried your code is that I got errors on the line breaks. The reason that this happens for me and not for you is (presumably) that you're using Windows line breaks (`\r\n`) and I'm not. Your lexer recognizes `\r\n` as a line break and skips it, but just `\n` is recognized as a `CHAR`.
- Further your handling of spaces is very confusing. Single spaces are their own tokens. They have to appear in certain places and can't appear anywhere else. However multiple consecutive spaces are skipped. So something like `int  main` would be an error because it would not detect a space between `int` and `main`. On the other hand indenting a line with a single space would be an error because then the indentation would not be skipped.
- Your identifiers are also wonky. Identifiers can contain spaces (as long as it's more than one), line breaks (as long as they're `\r\n` or you fix it, so that `\n` is skipped, too) or comments. So the following would be a single valid identifier (assuming you change the lexer, so that the letters are recognized as `ALPHA` instead of `CHAR`):

  ```
  hel  lo  //comment
  wor
  ld
  ```

  On the other hand `maintarget` would not be a valid identifier because it contains the keyword `int`.
- Similarly skipped tokens can also be used inside your integer literals and string literals. For string literals that means that `"a  b"` is a valid string (which is fine) that only contains the characters `a` and `b` (which is not fine) because the double space gets skipped. On the other hand `" "` would be a invalid string because  is recognized as a `' '` token, not a `CHAR` token. Also if you fix your identifiers by making letters be recognized as `ALPHA`, they will no longer be valid inside strings. Also `"la//la"` would be seen as an unclosed string literal because `//la"` would be seen as comment.

All of these issues are related to how the lexer works, so let's go through that:

---

When turning a character stream into a token stream, the lexer will process the input according to the "maximal munch" rule: It will go through all of the lexer rules and checks which one matches at the beginning of the current input. Of those that match, it will pick the one that produces the longest match. In case of ties it will prefer the one that's defined first in the grammar. If you use string literals directly in parser rules, they are treated like lexer rules that are defined before any others.

So the fact that you have a `CHAR: .;` rule that comes before `ALPHA`, `DIGIT` and `HEX_DIGIT` means that these rules will never be matched. All of these rules match a single character, so when more than one of them matches, `CHAR` will be preferred because it comes first in the grammar. If you move `CHAR` to the end, letters will now be matched by `ALPHA`, decimal digits by `DIGIT` and everything else by `CHAR`. This still leaves `HEX_DIGIT` useless (and if you move it to the front, that would render `ALPHA` and `DIGIT` useless) and it also means that `CHAR` no longer does what you want because you *want* digits and letters to be seen as `CHAR`s - but only inside strings.

The real problem here is that none of these things should be tokens. They should either be `fragment`s or just be inlined directly into the lexer rules that use them. Instead your tokens should be anything inside of which you don't want to allow/ignore spaces or comments. So string literals, int literals and identifiers should all be tokens. The only instance where you have multiple lexer rules that could match the same input should be identifiers and keywords (where keywords take precedence over identifiers because you specify them as string literals in the grammar, but longer identifiers could still contain keywords as a substring because of the maximal munch rule).

You also should remove all uses of `' '` from your grammar and instead always skip spaces.